# Can't find GitXcode in the Source Control Menu

Tags: xcode, github

I would like to add a link to a repository from Github in Xcode 10.
According to the guides I need to see this on the menu in Xcode :

[image]

But, in my menu there is no "working copies" , only commit/push/pull, etc.
Cant see the selected row from the photo here.

Why ?

Comment: Can you update your question with what you mean by "add a link to a repository from Github"? Can you also update your question with a link or additional explanation about "the guides" that say you need to deal with working copies?

Answer (score -1):

What is the difference between Git and GitHub?

Git is a version control system; think of it as a series of snapshots (commits) of your code. You see a path of these snapshots, in which order they where created. You can make branches to experiment and come back to snapshots you took.

GitHub, is a web-page on which you can publish your Git repositories and collaborate with other people.

Is Git saving every repository locally (in the user's machine) and in GitHub?

No, it's only local. You can decide to push (publish) some branches on GitHub.

Can you use Git without GitHub? If yes, what would be the benefit for using GitHub?

Yes, Git runs local if you don't use GitHub. An alternative to using GitHub could be running Git on files hosted on Dropbox, but GitHub is a more streamlined service as it was made especially for Git.

How does Git compare to a backup system such as Time Machine?

It's a different thing, Git lets you track changes and your development process. If you use Git with GitHub, it becomes effectively a backup. However usually you would not push all the time to GitHub, at which point you do not have a full backup if things go wrong. I use git in a folder that is synchronized with Dropbox.

Is this a manual process, in other words if you don't commit you won't have a new version of the changes made?

Yes, committing and pushing are both manual.

Comment: is that an AI answer ? because it is not relate to the question.